# smooth plotting all columns of a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, plot, smoothing

I have a data frame of:

```
Index   Date        AA   BB   CC     DD    EE   FF
0       2019-01-15  0.0  -1.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  2.0
1       2019-01-17  0.0  -1.0  -1.0  -1.0  0.0  2.0
2       2019-01-22  1.0  -1.0  1.0   -1.0  0.0  2.0
3       2019-01-24  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  2.0
4       2019-01-29  1.0  0.0   -1.0  0.0   -1.0 2.0
5       2019-01-31  0.0  -1.0  0.0   0.0   0.0  2.0
6       2019-02-05  1.0  1.0   1.0   0.0   1.0  2.0
7       2019-02-12  2.0  1.0   1.0   0.0   2.0  2.0
```

which I'm plotting with:

```py
dfs = dfs.melt('Date', var_name = 'cols', value_name = 'vals')
ax = sns.lineplot(x = "Date", y = 'vals', hue = 'cols', 
                  style = 'cols', markers = True, dashes = False, data = dfs)
ax.set_xticklabels(dfs['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
plt.xticks(rotation = -90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

resulting:

which is ugly. I want to have the markers in the exact place as what is in the data-frame but the lines to be smoothed. I'm aware of `scipy -> spline` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283649/plot-smooth-line-with-pyplot)), however that seems to be too much hassle to convert all the columns. There is also `Pandas -> resample -> interpolate` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097015/plot-smooth-curves-of-pandas-series-data)) which is very close to what I want but I have to turn the `Date` column to `index` which I don't want to do...

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the best Pythonic way to do this.

---

**P.S.** A complete version of my code can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/2be6d4105bcdccf4dc74810e1885ec3e).

Comment: I see you are using `seaborn`. It helps if you add the tag in your question to get answers.

Comment: @Erfan Well, it is not really a necessity. Any solution without seaborn is also OK for me.

Comment: How do you expect the smoothing to happen, specifically, if you don't want to add any points in-between?

Comment: @JohanL I actually don't mind points to be added in between. I want the markers only to be shown for the actual data. So with matplotlib I usually plot twice once with the scatter and then plot the smoothed data.

Comment: And why not doing that now?

Comment: [I'm actually trying](https://i.imgur.com/v2WK5xF.png) but it is not what I want.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was, you can always do `df_tmp = dfs.set_index()....` and do stuff on `df_tmp` without touching to data.

Comment: @Foad: That is what to be expected from raw interpolation, that you end up with extreme data. Try some other interpolation method, e.g. cubic spline, which may not give the same huge dip.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write a custom plotting function that iterates over all
columns and plots interpolated data to specified axes instance. Look at the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data = pd.read_clipboard()
# data.drop(['Index'], axis=1, inplace=True)

def add_smooth_plots(df, ax,  timecolumn='Date', interpolation_method='cubic', colors='rgbky'):
    from itertools import cycle
    ind = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, timecolumn])
    tick_labels =ind.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    color = cycle(colors)
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        if col != timecolumn:
            c = next(color)
            s = pd.Series(df.loc[:, col].values, index=ind)
            intp = s.resample('0.5D').interpolate(method=interpolation_method)
            true_ticks = intp.index.isin(ind)
            vals = intp.values
            intp = intp.reset_index()
            ticks = intp.index[true_ticks]
            ax.plot(np.arange(len(vals)), vals, label=col, color=c)
            ax.set_xticks(ticks)
            ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels.values, rotation=45)
            ax.legend(title='Columns')
    return ax

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

add_smooth_plots(data, ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look into this tonight and will get back to you. 