# Is there any way to suppress/normalize/average out peaks in graph in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, data-science

I am working on data visualization problem, where I am plotting daily active users on about 15k pages against time/dates in python. On some days, I have peaks on specific page, but those peaks are artificially created and affect cumulative results. I want to show overall trends, either by suppressing peaks or adjusting the data in some other way.

I am plotting using Pandas with Python, in jupyter notebook.

**Question: Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?**

[Sample Graph is attached, Red line is original graph, where blue line is my attempt to suppress peaks. On x-axis, date is mentioned, on y-axis, sum of daily traffic is ploted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg6TX.png)

Comment: Hi @Developer_, welcome to Stackoverflow! Without further information it's nigh on impossible to give a very good answer – really you should include a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  That said, some form of moving average would probably be the most common way to deal with this.  For example `df.rolling(window=5).mean()` would compute the rolling mean over a five day period.  This will have the effect of smoothing out the curve – larger windows mean more smoothing and vice versa.

Comment: Also, check out this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097015/plot-smooth-curves-of-pandas-series-data. It may help